# Javascript Jquery How the get the name of $(this) Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, key, this

I'm interested by retrieving the name / object key (I dont know how to call that) of a `$(this)` object.

By example, when you do a `console.log` of `$(this)` in a click event, firebug print :

> Object[h1#Title.uppercase.ui-draggable]

I'm interested by getting this :

> h1#Title.uppercase.ui-draggable

How can I do it ?

---

EDIT :

I find a way to recompose what I want with a little script, here it is :

```js
var tag = $(this).prop('tagName').toLowerCase();
var id = $(this).prop('id');

if(id.length>0){
  var id = '#'+id;
}else{
  var id = '';
}

var classes = $(this).prop('class');

if(classes.length>0){

  var class_list = classes.split(' ');
  var class_chain = '';   
  for(i=0;i<class_list.length;i++){
    class_chain = class_chain+'.'+class_list[i];
  }

}else{
  var class_chain = '';
}

var complete_chain = tag+id+class_chain;
```

Comment: $(anything in here) is a jquery object - it's quite complex, and does not have a name or a single key

Comment: You have to decide wether you want the tagname, the ID, the class, the original selector or what, and why you would need it.

Comment: `$(this).selector` is what you're looking for

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the jquery object and simply want to print the element, use this

```
console.log($(this)[0]);
```

If you are interested to get the name attribute of your html element, use this

```
console.log($(this).attr('name'));
```

If you want to same output as you want, use this

```
console.log($(this).prop("tagName")+"#"+$(this).attr('id')+"."+$(this).attr('class'));
```